# Database ERD Design

Tags: sql, erd

Hi I'll make small social media and I'd want to know if my plan in the ERD is good to continue.

[image]

For now I have 5 tables - user, user_profile, user_address, friend_list, friend_request_list

****user 1 isto 1 user_profile**

**user_profile 1 to many user_address**

**user_profile 1 to many friend_list**

**user_profile 1 to many friend_request_list****

I'm confused in this relationship below

**friend_list many to 1 user**

**friend_request_list many to 1 user**

Can I know how to improve my design?

Comment: maybe dont include that `friend_list many to 1 user` and `friend_request_list many to 1 user` because `user` is already have a relationship in `user_profile` which is connected to `friend_list` and frient_request_list`

Comment: ok thx but how about in querying? select * from user where id is = id?

Comment: this will help you. [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

late to the party but in case you'r still needing help on this, then i've got quite a few things that you could take into consideration, lets just start by each table.

USERS:

- make gender a table, and ref by ID (so many genders these days, you might need to add support for more than Male/Female(0/1 in your bool)
- make age a calculated field from the birthdate this should just auto increment depending on the birthdate set.
- make user_role table and ref by ID (a role could be implemented on many users, might aswell normalize it)

USER_PROFILE
not much here

USER_ADDRESS

- i would probably myself have made a relation to USER and not USER_PROFILE, seems more coherent

FRIEND_LIST

- remove relations between FRIEND_LIST & USER, FRIEND_REQUEST_LIST & USER, these are already related through the user profile

last notes, your relationpointers are really confusing, you'r e.g. indicating that USER has *..1 and 1..1 and  1..0 to USER_PROFILE